# adding activity to a file

Tags: c, function, file, line

When I try to add activity to my text file which looks like this:

```
S1,CM004;CM020;E001
S2,CM010;CM009;CM004;CM006;SM001;E001;SM002;PC007
S3,CM020;CM17;T001
```

I can't add it. When I add it to S1 student it doesn't add the end of the line. Is there a way to add an activity in the end like this ;E002 or ;CM003. simply I just want to add activity to the end of the line.

```
typedef struct {
    char studentID[20];
    char activities[50][10];
    int activityCount;
} StudentDetails;


void addActivity(const char *studentID, const char *codeToAdd) {
    FILE *studentFile = fopen("StudentAccounts.txt", "r+");

    if (studentFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening student file");
        return;
    }

    StudentDetails studentDetails;
    int found = 0;

    // Read student's chosen activities
    while (fscanf(studentFile, "%19[^,],", studentDetails.studentID) == 1) {
        // Check if the student ID matches
        if (strcmp(studentDetails.studentID, studentID) == 0) {
            found = 1;
            studentDetails.activityCount = 0;

            // Read and store existing activities
            while (fscanf(studentFile, "%9[^;];", studentDetails.activities[studentDetails.activityCount]) == 1) {
                trimWhitespace(studentDetails.activities[studentDetails.activityCount]);
                studentDetails.activityCount++;

                if (studentDetails.activityCount >= 50) {
                    printf("Warning: Maximum number of activities reached.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Add the new activity if not already present
            int activityFound = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < studentDetails.activityCount; i++) {
                if (strcmp(studentDetails.activities[i], codeToAdd) == 0) {
                    activityFound = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!activityFound) {
                // Append the new activity code
                strncpy(studentDetails.activities[studentDetails.activityCount], codeToAdd, sizeof(studentDetails.activities[0]));
                studentDetails.activityCount++;

                // Move file pointer back to the beginning of the line
                fseek(studentFile, -strlen(studentDetails.studentID) - 1, SEEK_CUR);

                // Write updated activities to the file
                for (int i = 0; i < studentDetails.activityCount; i++) {
                    fprintf(studentFile, "%s;", studentDetails.activities[i]);
                }

                // Break out of the loop since we found and updated the student
                break;
            }
        }

        // Skip the rest of the line
        while (fgetc(studentFile) != '\n') {
            // Check for end of file
            if (feof(studentFile)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(studentFile);

    if (!found) {
        printf("Student ID %s not found.\n", studentID);
    } else {
        printf("Activity code %s added to student %s.\n", codeToAdd, studentID);
    }
}


int studentRole(const char ID[20]) {
    int choice;
    char codeToChange[20];
    char codeToAdd[20];
    char codeToDelete[20];
    int coreCredits = 0;
    int coreModulesSelected = 0; // Count of selected core modules

    do {
        printf("\nMenu:\n");
        printf("1. View/Track activities and credits\n");
        printf("2. Select an Core Module\n");
        printf("3. Delete an Core Module\n");
        printf("4. Select Activity\n");
        printf("5. Delete an Activity\n");
        printf("6. Quit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter a number.\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n'); // Clear input buffer
            continue;
        }

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                ViewActivitiesWithPoints(ID); // Call the function to display credits and points
                break;
            case 2:
                ShowActivities("CM");
                printf("Enter the code of the activity to add: ");
                scanf("%s", codeToAdd);
                while (getchar() != '\n'); // Clear input buffer
                // Add the activity to the list of chosen activities and also write it to Activity.txt
                addActivity(ID,codeToAdd);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Enter the code of the activity to delete from your Activity.txt file: ");
                scanf("%s", codeToDelete);
                deleteActivity(ID, codeToDelete,"CM");
                break;
            case 4:
                ShowActivities("E");
                ShowActivities("SM");
                ShowActivities("W");
                ShowActivities("CS");
                ShowActivities("PS");
                ShowActivities("PC");
                ShowActivities("CMP");
                ShowActivities("T");

                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Enter the code of the core module to delete: ");
                scanf("%s", codeToDelete);
                //deleteData(activities, &count, "coreModules.txt", codeToDelete,"CM");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
        }
    } while (choice != 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the position of the code in seek_cur other than that. I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. Also [edit] and show _my file which looks like this_ properly formatted.

Comment: `perror("StudentAccounts.txt")` gives a more informative error message.  Don't make the user guess the name of the file, or rely on the user having a priori knowledge of what the filename is.

Comment: You need to be careful about how you are using `feof`.  If there is a read error on the file, this likely to become an infinite loop.

Comment: Rather than trying to insert data, you will find it much easier to write a new file and replace the original at the end of processing.

Comment: @Yehia Alhaddad – You must realize that when you are overwriting a line with a longer line, you also overwrite what's after the line (on common OS).

Comment: Welcome to SO. As an additional hint, this "I can't add it. When I add it to S1 student it doesn't add the end of the line." is not a useful description of your problem. You should also tell us what happens instead. Provide detailled information about what you want to add, what output you want to achieve and also what you get instead. In this special case it might be obvious for some users but we should not need to guess what other result you expect. And on the other side, you should remove unrelated code. If you have a problem with adding, you can easily remove the code for displaying etc..

Comment: When I tried some of this code, the statement ```fscanf(studentFile, "%9[^;];", studentDetails.activities[studentDetails.activityCount])``` didn't cope with line-endings. It read them as just another activity on the first line. You either need to fix the `fscanf` pattern or to read an entire line and then to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

A file is a sequence of bytes. When your file “looks like”:

```
S1,CM004;CM020;E001
S2,CM010;CM009;CM004;CM006;SM001;E001;SM002;PC007
S3,CM020;CM17;T001
```

then the bytes in the file, starting near the end of the first line, are E, 0, 0, 1, newline, S, 2, comma, C, M, and so on. When your program seeks to the end of the first line and uses `fprintf` to write “;E002”, it does not insert those bytes in the file; it overwrites the bytes in the file. So the new bytes overwrite the newline character and the S, 2, C, M, and other bytes that follow those, thus destroying the second line of the file.

The standard C library routines to not provide any way to insert bytes in a file, and neither do the I/O routines of most operating systems. There is basically no feasible way to do this because the bytes of a file are stored in consecutive positions on disk (some physically consecutive within a disk block, some logically consecutive across multiple blocks), and inserting a few bytes would require reading every following byte in the file and rewriting all those bytes to new positions. (Inserting a whole disk block might be feasible to support, although it introduces complications for the file system.)

To update a file in the way you want to do, it is necessary to write a new file, as by reading the input file and writing a new version to a different output file, after which you could move the new output file to replace the original input file, if desired.

Commercial databases avoid this problem by organizing the file with various data structures, so that the contents are not a single stream of characters but are records in blocks or other units.

Comment: so basically I have to add structure for the code to work or else it will not?

Comment: @YehiaAlhaddad: You must either design a structure for the file contents or you must update records by writing an entirely new file.

Answer (score 1):

At least 4 issues are apparent:

- Once you have the records updated in memory, you need to update the whole file. Because the lines are of variable length, you cannot just seek back to the start of the line.
- In order to overwrite the whole file, you will need to load all of the records into memory, even though you will not be updating most of them.
- If the count of activities for a record exceeds 50 when loading, you need to reset it back to 50. Otherwise, an array will be overrun when outputting the records.
- The current code for reading the file doesn't seem to recognise new lines.